# How do you prevent VS debugger from showing exception on every await?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

In a call stack which contains several await statements, when an exception is thrown, the debugger keeps showing the error at each await statement.  I was wondering if there's a way to have the debugger only show the initial place where the exception is thrown, but not stop at ever await.

Comment: I suspect the reason it's not failing at the real exception point is that it's effecticly an uncaught exception.  If you put `try/catch` around the root of the `await`s then you might get more/relevant information.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  Getting an exception in async code is pretty painful.  You'd consider forcing the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown so you can fix the problem.  Great, problem fixed, but don't forget to disable it again.

Comment: @HansPassant, not sure if I understand, we have code which throws exceptions, but higher level code may decide a particular exception is ok, so it goes through several layers of async methods to finally be "handled" (ignored).  In our case, we try to resolve an object by name, but if we don't find it, that might be OK, depending on if it happens when it's needed, or it is being done before it might be needed.  So there might be exceptions coming from that code, but there may also be exceptions from other places, it's just that stopping on every await doesn't add value, that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

How about `System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden` attribute? This attribute is used to hide a method or property from the debugger which also prevent debugger from intercepting exception.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden]
private static void SecretRun(IEnumerable<int> ints)
{
   foreach (var i in ints)
   {
       try
       {
           if (i < 50) Console.WriteLine("next" + i);
           else throw new Exception("some exception");
       }
       catch
       {
           // Ignored
       }
    }
}
```

**Cons:** You will not be able to debug into a method tagged with `DebuggerHidden` attribute.

In order to use this attribute, you need to check **"Enable Just My Code"** at `Tools > Options > Debugging > General`

Comment: The problem with this is that you are forced to ignore exceptions in too many methods.  Probably to solve the problem @Alex has, there needs to be a Visual Studio upgrade because VS only filters which exceptions to stop on based on this attribute, and the type of exception.  But to do what the the OP wants, it would need to filter based on whether the exception had already been stopped on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a setting for what you've mentioned. But if there is a specific error that you are trying to catch/debug then you can change your exception settings (ctrl + alt + E) and tick "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". This will break on the initial error. Then just right click, restore defaults when you're done.

[image]